# How to store java toggle as value in sql?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, toggle, togglebutton

I have a shoutbox as an overlay on my website (it's always displayed) which you can minimize and enlarge by pressing a button (toggle).

The problem is, that when I go to different pages on my website, the shoutbox initially is always open. This is annoying. I would like to store the information of whether the user has minimized the shoutbox or not (eg in a sql db), so that the state of the shoutbox does not always go back .

Any help would be appreciated!!

Below the code of my shoutbox:

```
load_data = {'fetch':1};
 $.post('<?php echo THEMEPATH; ?>/shout.php', load_data,  function(data) {
    $('.message_box').html(data);
    var scrolltoh = $('.message_box')[0].scrollHeight;
    $('.message_box').scrollTop(scrolltoh);
 });

//method to trigger when user hits enter key
$("#shout_message").keypress(function(evt) {
    if(evt.which == 13) {
            var iusername = "<?php echo $login; ?>";
            var imessage = $('#shout_message').val();
            post_data = {'username':iusername, 'message':imessage};

            //send data to "shout.php" using jQuery $.post()
            $.post('<?php echo THEMEPATH; ?>/shout.php', post_data, function(data) {

                //append data into messagebox with jQuery fade effect!
                $(data).hide().appendTo('.message_box').fadeIn();

                //keep scrolled to bottom of chat!
                var scrolltoh = $('.message_box')[0].scrollHeight;
                $('.message_box').scrollTop(scrolltoh);

                //reset value of message box
                $('#shout_message').val('');

            }).fail(function(err) { 

            //alert HTTP server error
            alert(err.statusText); 
            });
        }
});

//toggle hide/show shout box
$(".close_btnn").click(function (e) {   
    //get CSS display state of .toggle_chat element
    var toggleState = $('.toggle_chat').css('display');

    //toggle show/hide chat box
    $('.toggle_chat').slideToggle();

    //use toggleState var to change close/open icon image
    if(toggleState == 'block')
    {
        $(".header div").attr('class', 'open_btnn');
    }else{
        $(".header div").attr('class', 'close_btnn');
    }


});
```

Comment: you can use localStorage for state localStorage.setItem('key', 'value') localStorage.getItem('key')

Comment: could you give me an example of how that would look in my code?

Comment: localStorage.setItem($.key, $value); A cookie would be better though because your server has no access to local storage, if you set a cookie then you can send different code with the box minimised from server level, rather than relying on the visiotor to do it client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So what you'll want to do is to use cookies in PHP so for example try this:

shout.php (at end of file before content is returned)

```
setcookie("COOKIENAMEHERE", $output_message, time() + (86400 * 30), '/'); // 86400 = 1 day, therefore 30 days
```

Then to retrieve the cookie on your pages, you can set the content in the html page (please provide your HTML/PHP so I can adapt it to your scenario):

```
<?php
$cookie_name = 'COOKIENAMEHERE';
if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) { ?>
  <div class="message_box">
     <?php echo $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]; ?>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
```

In order to make the shout box hidden by default put this in your css file:

```
.message_box {
    display: none;
}
```

Also if/when you want to update or delete the cookie you just do the same as creating to update and to delete:

```
$cookie_name = 'COOKIENAMEHERE';
unset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]); //removes the cookie from memory
// empty value and expiration one hour before just to be sure
$result = setcookie($cookie_name, '', time() - 3600);
```

**EDIT:** For your code

```
...

elseif($_POST["fetch"]==1)
{
    $results = mysqli_query($sql_con,"SELECT user, message, date_time FROM (select * from table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) table ORDER BY table.id ASC");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
        $output_message = $output_message.'<div class="shout_msg"><time>'.$row["date_time"].'</time><span class="username">'.$row["user"].'</span> <span class="message">'.$row["message"].'</span></div>';
    }
    setcookie("shout_msg", $output_message, time() + (86400 * 30), '/'); // 86400 = 1 day, therefore 30 days
    echo $output_message;
}
else
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Are you kiddin me?');
    exit();
}
}
```

In your index.php file:

```
<div class="header">Shout Box <div class="close_btn">&nbsp;</div></div>
  <div class="toggle_chat">
  <?php
$cookie_name = 'shout_msg';
if(isset($_COOKIE[$cookie_name])) { ?>
  <div class="message_box">
     <?php echo $_COOKIE[$cookie_name]; ?>
  </div>
<?php } ?>
    <div class="user_info">

   <input name="shout_message" id="shout_message" type="text" placeholder="Type Message Hit Enter" maxlength="100" /> 
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Unless I'm reading it wrong you are fading .message_box in so add this to your css:

```
.message_box {
    display: none;
}
```

**PRO TIP:** Put your scripts just before the closing body tag to speed up your website, having it in the head makes it load slower.

Answer (score 0):

This is the HTML/PHP of the page with the shoutbox;

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.shout_box {
background: #000000;
width: 260px;
overflow: hidden;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 10px;
z-index:9;
}
.shout_box .header .close_btn {
background: url(close_btn.gif) no-repeat 0px 0px;
float: right;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
}
.shout_box .header .close_btn:hover {
background: url(close_btn.gif) no-repeat 0px -16px;
}

.shout_box .header .open_btn {
background: url(close_btn.gif) no-repeat 0px -32px;
float: right;
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
}
.shout_box .header .open_btn:hover {
background: url(close_btn.gif) no-repeat 0px -48px;
}
.shout_box .header{
padding: 5px 3px 5px 5px;
font: 11px 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: bold;
color:#fff;
border: 1px solid rgba(0, 39, 121, .76);
border-bottom:none;
cursor: pointer;
}
.shout_box .header:hover{
background-color: #000000;
}
.shout_box .message_box {
background: #FFFFFF;
height: 200px;
overflow:auto;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
}
.shout_msg{
margin-bottom: 10px;
display: block;
border-bottom: 1px solid #F3F3F3;
padding: 0px 5px 5px 5px;
font: 11px 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
color:#7C7C7C;
}
.message_box:last-child {
border-bottom:none;
}
time{
    font: 11px 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
font-weight: normal;
float:right;
color: #D5D5D5;
}
.shout_msg .username{
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
}
.user_info input {
width: 98%;
height: 25px;
border: 1px solid #CCC;
border-top: none;
padding: 3px 0px 0px 3px;
font: 11px 'lucida grande', tahoma, verdana, arial, sans-serif;
}
.shout_msg .username{
font-weight: bold;
display: block;
}
-->
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="shoutbox/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

// load messages every 1000 milliseconds from server.
load_data = {'fetch':1};
//window.setInterval(function(){
 $.post('shoutbox/shout.php', load_data,  function(data) {
    $('.message_box').html(data);
    var scrolltoh = $('.message_box')[0].scrollHeight;
    $('.message_box').scrollTop(scrolltoh);
 });
//}, 1000);

//method to trigger when user hits enter key
$("#shout_message").keypress(function(evt) {
    if(evt.which == 13) {
            var iusername = "java";
            var imessage = $('#shout_message').val();
            post_data = {'username':iusername, 'message':imessage};

            //send data to "shout.php" using jQuery $.post()
            $.post('shoutbox/shout.php', post_data, function(data) {

                //append data into messagebox with jQuery fade effect!
                $(data).hide().appendTo('.message_box').fadeIn();

                //keep scrolled to bottom of chat!
                var scrolltoh = $('.message_box')[0].scrollHeight;
                $('.message_box').scrollTop(scrolltoh);

                //reset value of message box
                $('#shout_message').val('');

            }).fail(function(err) { 

            //alert HTTP server error
            alert(err.statusText); 
            });
        }
});

//toggle hide/show shout box
$(".close_btn").click(function (e) {
    //get CSS display state of .toggle_chat element
    var toggleState = $('.toggle_chat').css('display');

    //toggle show/hide chat box
    $('.toggle_chat').slideToggle();

    //use toggleState var to change close/open icon image
    if(toggleState == 'block')
    {
        $(".header div").attr('class', 'open_btn');
    }else{
        $(".header div").attr('class', 'close_btn');
    }


});
});

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="shout_box">
<div class="header">Shout Box <div class="close_btn">&nbsp;</div></div>
  <div class="toggle_chat">
  <div class="message_box">
    </div>
    <div class="user_info">

   <input name="shout_message" id="shout_message" type="text" placeholder="Type Message Hit Enter" maxlength="100" /> 
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is the php of my shout.php:

```
if($_POST)
{
//connect to mysql db
$sql_con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name)or die('could not connect to database');

//check if its an ajax request, exit if not
if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {
    die();
} 

if(isset($_POST["message"]) &&  strlen($_POST["message"])>0)
{
    //sanitize user name and message received from chat box
    //You can replace username with registerd username, if only registered users are allowed.
    $message = filter_var(trim($_POST["message"]),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
    $date = date("Y-m-d H:i");
    $username = filter_var(trim($_POST["username"]),FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_LOW | FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
    //insert new message in db
    if(mysqli_query($sql_con,"INSERT INTO table(user, message, date_time) value('$username','$message','$date')"))
    {
        //$msg_time = date('h:i Y-m-d',time()); // current time
        $msg_time = date("Y-m-d H:i");
        echo '<div class="shout_msg"><time>'.$msg_time.'</time><span class="username">'.$username.'</span><span class="message">'.$message.'</span></div>';
    }


}
elseif($_POST["fetch"]==1)
{
    $results = mysqli_query($sql_con,"SELECT user, message, date_time FROM (select * from table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10) table ORDER BY table.id ASC");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {

        echo '<div class="shout_msg"><time>'.$row["date_time"].'</time><span class="username">'.$row["user"].'</span> <span class="message">'.$row["message"].'</span></div>';
    }
}
else
{
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Are you kiddin me?');
    exit();
}
}
```